# Root Test Convergence Question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The root test can be applied to series whose terms involve a **factorial**.

$$\int_1^n \ln(x) \, dx < \ln(1)+\ln(2)+\dots+\ln(n) < \int_1^{n+1} \ln(x) \, dx$$

a) Find functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ so that $f(n) < \ln(n!) < g(n)$.

b) Using the Squeeze Theorem with those two functions, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {(n!)^\frac{1}{n}} n.$ (If the squeeze theorem doesn't work, pick different functions in part b and try again.)

c) Apply the root test to each of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(2^n)n!} {n^n} $ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(3^n)n!} {n^n} $, and explain your conclusions.
This is what I've done so far:

Comment: Evaluate the integrals in a to get your $f(n)$ and $g(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_1^n \ln(x) \, dx < \ln(1)+\ln(2)+\dots+\ln(n) < \int_1^{n+1} \ln(x) \, dx$

$$=\int_1^n \ln(x) \, dx < \ln(n!) < \int_1^{n+1} \ln(x) \, dx.$$

Use Integration-by-Parts for $ln(x) dx$:

$$\left| \begin{array}{cc} u=ln(x) & dv=dx \\ du=\frac{1}{x} dx & v=x \end{array} \right|$$

So we get:

$$\int \ln(x) dx = xln(x)-\int\frac{x}{x}dx$$

$$=xln(x)-\int1dx$$

$$=xln(x)-x+C.$$

Now compute the limits for the left side, and you get:

$$nln(n)-n+1.$$

Now compute the limits for the right side, and you get:

$$(n+1)(ln(n+1)-n.$$

Thus we get:
 $$f(n) = nln(n)-n+1$$ $$g(n)=(n+1)(ln(n+1)-n).$$